matplotlib uses tight layout even though `plt.tight_layout()` is not called
I copied and pasted code from this matplotlib demo into my python IDE, and the figure it produced had smaller figure margins than the demo figure. It looks to me like matplotlib is calling tight layout internally. How do I force matplotlib to use the original/demo margins?
I've tried resetting rcParams to the defaults (with plt.rcParams.update(matplotlib.rcParamsDefault)),  restarting the environment, and even running the code in a different environment. I'm using matplotlib version 3.8.4.
Code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
bar_labels = ['red', 'blue', '_red', 'orange']
bar_colors = ['tab:red', 'tab:blue', 'tab:red', 'tab:orange']

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=bar_labels, color=bar_colors)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()

Graphs


You might want to check your matplotlibrc file to see if it has tight layout enabled by default

In my matplotlibrc file, figure.autolayout and figure.constrained_layout.use are both False.

Are you doing this in a Jupyter notebook?  In which case it is using bbox_inches=tight

This wasn't in a Jupyter notebook. I tried this code in Spyder and on google colaboratory. However, the line %config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None} resolved the issue.
